# Google Map Clustering Is Not Working With Info Windows

Tags: javascript

Below is the javascript code that I have in my file.

............................................................................................................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................
..............................................................................

```js
<script>
        var map;
        var InforObj = [];
        var centerCords = {
            lat: 42.4519,
            lng: -83.43609
        };
        var markersOnMap = [{
                placeName: "Americana Estates",
                address: "5407 Aloha Lane, Casco, MI, 48064",
                addressLink: "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Americana+Estates+of+Casco/@42.7386738,-82.7299418,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x8825109b143319f5:0x4fc50b237bb5f9c9!8m2!3d42.7390147!4d-82.7274216",
                phone: "Call 586-749-5169",
                phoneLink: "tel:586-749-5169",
                websiteLink: "https://www.york-americanaestates.com/",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.73872, lng: -82.72808 }]
            },
            {
                placeName: "Arbor Knoll Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.20447, lng: -83.69314 }]
            },
            {
                placeName: "Ashbury Place Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.12653, lng: -83.21234 }]
            },
            {
                placeName: "Bridgewood Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.11713, lng: -83.28699 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Cambridge Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.33896, lng: -83.31214 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Glens of Northville Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.4417, lng: -83.46313 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Heights of Novi",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.4519, lng: -83.43609 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Legacy Place",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.45781, lng: -83.20854 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Orchards of Newburgh",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.34334, lng: -83.40822 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Orion Cove Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.77281, lng: -83.24194 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Orleans Place Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.13748, lng: -83.24922 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Plymouth House Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.35734, lng: -83.46253 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Plymouth Manor Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.35467, lng: -83.45953 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "The Park at Sagebrush Circle",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.26836, lng: -83.78569 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Round Hill Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.62152, lng: -83.42639 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Sunset Plaza Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.92254, lng: -83.62385 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Venoy Pines Apartments",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.33807, lng: -83.36682 }]
            },
             {
                placeName: "Westridge Mobile Home Park",
                LatLng: [{ lat: 42.26391, lng: -83.55855 }]
            }
        ];
        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
        
        window.onload = function () {
            initMap();
        };

        function addMarkerInfo() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
                var contentString = '<div id="infocontent"><h1>' + markersOnMap[i].placeName +
                    '</h1><p><a href="' + markersOnMap[i].addressLink + '" target="_blank">' + markersOnMap[i].address +
                    '</a><br /><br /><a href="' + markersOnMap[i].phoneLink + '">' + markersOnMap[i].phone +
                    '</a><br /><br /><a href="' + markersOnMap[i].websiteLink + '" target="_blank">View Property</a></p><br /></div>';

                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: markersOnMap[i].LatLng[0],
                    map: map
                });

                const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString,
                    maxWidth: 500
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    closeOtherInfo();
                    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
                    InforObj[0] = infowindow;
                });
                // marker.addListener('mouseover', function () {
                //     closeOtherInfo();
                //     infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
                //     InforObj[0] = infowindow;
                // });
                // marker.addListener('mouseout', function () {
                //     closeOtherInfo();
                //     infowindow.close();
                //     InforObj[0] = infowindow;
                // });
            }
        }

        function closeOtherInfo() {
            if (InforObj.length > 0) {
                /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
                InforObj[0].set("marker", null);
                /* and close it */
                InforObj[0].close();
                /* blank the array */
                InforObj.length = 0;
            }
        }

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 9,
                center: centerCords
            });
            addMarkerInfo();
        }
    </script>
```

```css
<style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #infocontent {
        background-color: #061e3a;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #infocontent h1 {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      #infocontent p {
        color: #ffffff;
      }
      #infocontent a {
        color: #ffffff;
      } 
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
    
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCiI58y7JXyz9sVXI5WQPTmMCu7psgSCcQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/map_cluster.js">
    </script>
```

I can get the info window click function to work correctly but clustering is not working. Can someone help with the clustering issue?

http://bhwnetwork.com/york/york_map_api_v3.html

Comment: Can you edit the post with the code that's causing the issue.

Comment: I have added my code to this post. Thank you.